# Javascript new File() gem file size

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have the following file structure:

```
test.html
test.json
```

And the following JS function:

```
function get_file(){
    var app_path = app.activeDocument.path,
        file = new File(app_path + '/test.json');  

    console.log(file);
}
```

How can I make the function log the file's content?

Comment: in node or some other JS environment?

Comment: @DanielA.White no, I am using pure Javascript

Comment: that doesn't mean a thing - do you mean in a browser?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, I'm actually developing for a Photoshop Extension

Comment: that makes a big difference. i've tagged your question appropriately.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh, thanks :) Can you help me though?

Comment: no sorry. i dont know the library well enough to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if everything you can do in the browsers environment translates to everything you can do in photoshops environment. But you should look at a few things.

**Doing This in the Browser**

The `File` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Notable that it extends the `Blob` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Which if you researched you would find it can be read using the `FileReader`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

So this would work in the browser but may/may-not work in the photoshop scripting set.

```
function get_file(){
    var app_path = app.activeDocument.path,
        file = new File(app_path + '/test.json');  

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

This is asynchronous so you may need to use a callback depending on what you're trying to do with this. You won't be able to return the string from inside the `reader.onloadend` event.

**Doing This in Photoshop**

Take a look at their scripting references. Specifically the javascript reference.

All Resources: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Javascript PDF: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf

It looks like they don't have the `FileReader` but instead the `File` object can be used to read content. The `File` API begins on page 109 but it's empty! The documentation is a bit pathetic so I can see why you'd have trouble finding this. With some searching I found someone doing this in 2012 (but I don't know if it will still work- worth a shot)

```
var b = new File("c:\test.txt");

b.open('r');

var str = "";
while(!b.eof) {
    str += b.readln();
}

b.close();

alert(str);
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: For some reason, `FileReader` returns an internal error from Photoshop, right from point where the `new FileReader` variable is defined. Any clues on how to overcome this issue?.

Comment: Updated. Not sure if that will work for you but give it a shot.